# Selecting column based on greater values between two other columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have table where I store results from soccer games.
I store each team score as well as it's id, and I want to get the id of the winning teams.

Here is the table

```
team1_id   team2_id   team1_score   team2_score
    1          2          1             0
    1          3          0             1    
    3          4          1             0
```

And here is what I want as result

```
1
3
```

(teams 1 and 3 won at least one game)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(team1_score > team2_score, team1_id, team2_id) AS winner
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/790483/1)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed